# subtraction operator python

Tags: python

I want to reduce the number of "the" words from a by 2. But this code doesn't seem to run. I cannot understand why the multiplication operator works but the subtraction operator doesn't.

```
b = "the"
a = b * 5
print a
a -= (b * 2)  
print a
```

output

```
the 
the the the the the 
Traceback (most recent call last):
    a -=  (b * 2)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'str' and 'str'
```

How can I reduce the number of "the" 's in a by 2. If this cannot be done like this then is there a easier method perform this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To reduce the number of "the" by 2 in you word, try with the [replace](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=replace#str.replace) method :

```
b = "the"
a = b * 5
print a
>>> "thethethethethe"
a = a.replace(b, "", 2)  # or a.replace(b*2, "", 1) if you want to remove "thethe" from the string
print a
>>> "thethethe"
```

If you wanted to remove the "the" by starting from the end, use [rsplit()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=replace#str.rsplit)

```
b = "the"
a = "theAtheBthethe"
a = "".join(a.rsplit("the", 2))   # or "".join(a.rsplit("thethe", 1)) if you want to remove "theth" of the string
print a
>>> "theAtheB"
```

As [described here](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=replace#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange), the * operator is supported by string (and unicode, list, tuple, bytearray, buffer, xrange types), `b * 5`  returns 5 copies of b concatenated.

Comment: This will "remove" the first occurences of characters within the string, so if you have 'theAtheBthethe', you won't get what you probably await...

Comment: a.replace doesn't actually change 'a'. you need to do a=a.replace(...)

Comment: @eumiro : right, I edited my answer to handle this possibility

Comment: There is some misunderstanding in your answer - `a -= (b * 2)` is not actually " _remove two "b" from "a"_ ", it is " _remove "b*2" from "a"_ ". The result differs for example when `a='theAtheBtheCtheDthe'` and `b='the'` - the result should be still `a='theAtheBtheCtheDthe'`, but your answer will give eg. `a='theAtheBtheCD'`.

Comment: @Tadeck : yes, I updated my answer with this possibility, let's the OP explain what he exactly wants ;)

Answer (score 4):

```
b = "the"
a = b * 5
print a

a = a[:-2*len(b)]
print a

# returns: thethethe
```

I am not substracting (you cannot really do it with strings), I am removing twice the length of `b` from the end of `a`, ignoring its real value.

Answer (score 2):

Depends if you want to chop them off the start or the end, you can use array subsets:

```
>>> a[2*len("the"):]
'thethethe'
>>> a[:-(2*len("the"))]
'thethethe'
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no support for subtraction operator in case of strings, but you can simply add one:

```
>>> class MyStr(str):
    def __init__(self, val):
        return str.__init__(self, val)
    def __sub__(self, other):
        if self.count(other) > 0:
            return self.replace(other, '', 1)
        else:
            return self
```

and this will work in the following way:

```
>>> a = MyStr('thethethethethe')
>>> b = a - 'the'
>>> a
'thethethethethe'
>>> b
'thethethethe'
>>> b = a - 2 * 'the'
>>> b
'thethethe'
```

Regarding `a - 2 * 'the'` operation you should be aware that this is not " *remove twice 'the' string from a* ", but " *remove result of (2 times 'the') from a* " (first multiply "`the`" by `2` and then subtract from `a`).

Is this what you expected?

Answer (score 1):

```
a = a.rpartition(b * 2)[0]
```

should do this, cutting from the right side. If you don't have any examples of `'thethe'` in `a`, it will return the empty string `''`. It won't work if you have multiple `'the'`s that are separated by other characters. For that, you could use `a.rpartition(b)[0]` twice. If you want to cut from the left instead, use `a.partition(b * 2)[2]`.

Why doesn't subtracting work? Using addition and multiplication is a convenience feature for working with strings. The semantics of subtracting (or dividing) `str`s is not defined for Python, so you can't use it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Plus operator work because "+" concatenate whilst minus don't operate on strings. You can try something using regular expression, like:

```
import re

s="the"*5
expr="the"

print s

# s -= 2
print "".join(re.findall(expr,s)[:-2])

# s -=3
print "".join(re.findall(expr,s)[:-3])
```